# In C, LARGE_INTEGER.QuadPart is catching twice in printf

Tags: c, printf

I'm trying to print out a file's size and name.

```
LARGE_INTEGER filesize;
filesize.LowPart = ...
...
printf("%ld %s\n", filesize.QuadPart, file.cFileName);
```

This results in

```
42 (null)
```

However when I slap on an extra %s (and a third for good measure)

```
printf("%ld %s %s %s\n", filesize.QuadPart, file.cFileName, "foo");
```

I get this

```
42 (null) hello.c foo
```

Obviously the easy fix is just to isolate filesize in its own printf statement but I'm still just dumbfounded as to why this happens.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: What is `LARGE_INTEGER`?

Comment: That's a 64-bit integer, not a long, you'll have to use %lld

Comment: @HansPassant: For 64 bit `int` one should use `(u)int64_t` and not some obscure/ancient macro or (missleadingly all-uppercase) `typedef`.However, OP should still show the definition. This is not standard C.

Comment: Not the first time I've been berated by somebody that doesn't know beans about the winapi.

Comment: @HansPassant: There is no clue it this is about WinAPI. You should no expect everyone knowing every obscure API or even every part of an API.

Comment: Hmya, SO users generally look for users that have a clue.  It isn't like you couldn't get one, the type name googles well and it is not obscure when it is used on a billion machines.  Please consider deleting your comments, they are not constructive.

Answer (score 0):

> The correct way to print would be `inttypes.h` with the macro `PRI64d`. –
>   Olaf

The standard way would be with the macro `PRId64`, e. g.

```
    printf("%"PRId64" %s\n", filesize.QuadPart, file.cFileName);
```

Answer (score 0):

`%lld` is what you're looking for.

Used like so:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdint.h>

typedef uint8_t BYTE;
typedef uint32_t DWORD;
typedef long int LONG;
typedef long long int LONGLONG;

typedef union _LARGE_INTEGER {
  struct {
    DWORD LowPart;
    LONG  HighPart;
  } DUMMYSTRUCTNAME;
  struct {
    DWORD LowPart;
    LONG  HighPart;
  } u;
  LONGLONG QuadPart;
} LARGE_INTEGER, *PLARGE_INTEGER;

int main()
{
    long long int d = LLONG_MAX;
    LARGE_INTEGER e;
    e.QuadPart = LLONG_MIN;
    printf("LONG LONG INT VALUE >> %lld \t %lld \n", d, e.QuadPart); 

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Why do you want to use LARGE_INTEGER? There is __int64 with native 64 support. There is also cstdint.h with int64_t (don't know if Visual Studio supports it, but other compilers do).

Also if you want to print such big variables, you need %I64d. That's MS's way to say "we don't support standarts".

Comment: The correct type would be `int64_t`. But the header is not `cstdint.h`, but `stdint.h`. This is about C, not C++. The correct way to print would be `inttypes.h` with the macro `PRI64d`.

Comment: @toohonestforthissite Prob a typo but the macro name is `PRId64`  (the 'd' goes before the 64).